# Perl.exe has stopped working

Tags: installing

When I tried to install Texlive2013 by running install-tl.bat, the message 'Perl.exe has stopped working' showed up. It failed too even I tried install-tl-advanced.bat while running it as an administrator. I also tried various ways including running it from command prompt with command like: -no gui something like that, which I found on the web but still it failed misearbly. Anyone has any idea? I run the installer from the iso I downloaded from CTAN server. I thought about installing it directly online but I scared it will fail too. I have my computer installed with strawberry Perl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [tlmgr error: perl.exe has stopped working](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47367/tlmgr-error-perl-exe-has-stopped-working)

Comment: Did you disable your virus  checker? (Note: the TL installer doesn't use 'locally installed' Perl, so Strawberry is irrelevant.)

Comment: @ChrisS i have tried every method metioned there

Comment: @JosephWright Yes i have turned it off.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem every time I ran the install-tl and selected 'simple install (big)'.  Running install-tl and selecting 'custom install' seems to have solved the problem for me.
Here's window's crash info if it helps anyone.

> Problem signature:
>    Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>    Application Name:    perl.exe
>    Application Version: 0.0.0.0
>    Application Timestamp:   50a6a593
>    Fault Module Name:   Tk.dll
>    Fault Module Version:    8.4.2.5
>    Fault Module Timestamp:  50a7fc99
>    Exception Code:  c0000005
>    Exception Offset:    00095910
>    OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
>    Locale ID:   1033
>    Additional Information 1:    0a9e
>    Additional Information 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>    Additional Information 3:    0a9e
>    Additional Information 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: What did you select in custom install routine, what have been the settings?

Comment: FYI, I have ran into this a _few_times on a PC. What I recall is that there are two different modes to install TeXLive, and when one failed I attempted to reinstall with the other mode and then it worked. I did not select any custom settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. Latex states right before the error message in the window on which package it was working. For me it was Cjkutil (chinese/japanese/korean), which I could untick at the install screen, so I could then install it without any issues. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I disabled my proxy and it worked for me (Windows 10).

To disable your proxy :

1. Open `Settings` ;
2. Click `Network & Internet` ;
3. Click `Proxy` ;
4. Turn off `Automatically detect settings` and `Use setup script`.

There you go.