# TeX Live manager: perl.exe stopped working

Tags: texlive, perl

I saw the same question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47367/tlmgr-error-perl-exe-has-stopped-working), and question was about TeXLive manager error `perl.exe stopped working`. However, many of answers was about this error during installation. I decided to create one more question.

So, what is the better to do if TeXLive Manager shows a popup saying

> perl exe stopped working

Please do not refer here about same error during installation.

Comment: So if not during installation, when is this error happening? What makes your question different from the one you are referring to?

Comment: During package update, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to avoid this error by doing things via a the command line in an Administrator cmd window.  Here is what I did:

1. Start an Administrator `cmd.exe`
2. Change directory to where the TeXLive binaries are (e.g., `cd c:\texlive\2014\bin\win32`)
3. Run `tlmgr.bat update foo`, where "foo" is the name of the package you want to update
4. As it happens I got an error in the previous step saying I needed to update the manager itself, so I actually did `tlmgr.bat update --self` before the previous step

However, I can't guarantee this works fully since the packages I was interested in had no updates.  Note, however, that when I tried this from the GUI I got the same error as you did; so the above at least gives no errors!

Comment: This didn't work for me...still get the damn perl error on 64-bit windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

I used install-tl-advanced.bat (as an administrator). First time it didn't work. I tried again at it worked perfectly! Maybe there is something wrong with Windows.

Comment: Using a similar approach, I reinstalled TexLive (I did it to the same directory, but you don't have to).  This fixed all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while updating TeXLive 2016. It seems like after a update the perl gets buged or something, during install there might be no errors at all.
Maybe some other program made the perl file corrupted, I don't know.

So this what I did and worked for me:

1. Browse to your `...\texlive\2016\tlpkg\` delete the whole `tlperl`
   directly, as this one contains the buged/corrupted perl version.
2. Download the [`install-tl-windows.exe`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) from TeX Users Group web site.
3. Run as Administrator (always)
4. Select unpack only and select a temporary folder

   [image: texlive installer unpack only]
5. Open the selected folder (mine looks like `install-tl-20160617`) and Copy the `tlperl` folder back into your original  `...\texlive\2016\tlpkg\`

Now the package manager should be running fine again. Hope that works for you too.

Comment: I tried this method. Unfortunately, it only made the situation worse. Before this patch I could run package manager, try to update packages (they wouldn't), then get an error (can't update, duh), and after that get the infamous 'perl.exe stopped working'. After the patch, perl crashes right after I click on 'package manager' in my tray. Win10x64, TeXLive2016, all freshly installed.

Comment: Any workaround for *non*-admin user accounts? Office IT policies don't allow users administrative, but if I have our IT guy install it under admin I constantly need to pester him for updating...

Comment: @Scard Did you try without admin account and it didn't work? It should work I guess, but as an alternative I would try to unpack it with 7zip or so.